# How to create use UICollectionView outline disclosure cell to work with VoiceOver

Tags: uikit, accessibility

I have collection view with hierarchical data source. Because of that, I create some cells with UICellAccessoryOutlineDisclosure accessory with style UICellAccessoryOutlineDisclosureStyleCell, so one can either tap on cell to open detail view or tap on outline disclosure accessory to reveal hidden child data.
Question: How should I configure outline disclosure accessory to work with VoiceOver on? It works fine without VoiceOver, but with VoiceOver it seems, that any gesture always leads to opening detail view.

So far it seems to me, that only solution to this is to create custom accessory button.